# Spring Scheduler stops working for my cron expression

Tags: spring, scheduler

I've a method scheduled to run periodically with Spring Scheduler, it's been working fine and stopped working today with no error. What could be the potential cause ? Is there any alternative way to schedule task periodically using Spring Scheduler that ensures that the method will be executed no matter what?

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0/1 * * * ?")
public void executePollingFlows(){
    if(applicationConfig.isScheduleEnabled()) {
        for (long flowId : applicationConfig.getPollingFlowIds()) {
            flowService.executeFlow(flowId);
        }
        logger.info("Finished executing all polling flows at {}", new Date());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have got Out of Memory exception if the job could not finish its tasks but you try to run it again and again. If it is a Out of Memory exception you may try to create a ThreadPool and check it in every run. If there is no enough space in the ThreadPool you can skip the task for this turn.

There is alternative way to use @Scheduled periodically. You may change your @Scheduled annotation with this:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate=1000)
```

It will still be running in every second and if necessary you can add initialDelay to it:

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay=1000, fixedRate=1000)
```

You can find more details about fixedRate, initialDelay and fixedDelay here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html